# What's the "correct" way to determine target and architecture for GNU binutils?

Tags: gcc, gnu, binutils

In my build chain, I need to do this:

```
objcopy -I binary -O $BFDNAME -B $BFDARCH <this> <that>
```

in order to get a binary file into library form. Because I want other people to be able to use this, I need to know how to get $BFDNAME and $BFDARCH from their toolchain when *they* run the build. I can get the values locally by running objdump -f against a file I've already built, but is there a better way which won't leave me compiling throw-away files just to get configuration values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out, regularfry! Your answer helped me to find another solution which works without specifying the architecture at all:

```
ld -r -b binary -o data.o data.txt
```

On my system (Ubuntu Linux, binutils 2.22) both objcopy and ld approaches produce identical object files.

All credit goes to:
http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.de/2008/08/cc-embed-binary-data-into-elf.html

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, the answer *seems* to be this: the first entry in the output of `objdump -i` is the default, native format of the system.