# How to add ARM_ATTRIBUTES section to a binary with objcopy

Tags: c++, c, linker, elf, objcopy

I'm trying to move a section from a proprietary binary into my own object file so that I can link against it. However the ARM architecture data is not being properly added to the generated object file, so it does not link into the final executable.

I do this with the following command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,contents,alloc,load,readonly,data
    -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm prop_fw.bin fw_data.o
```

When I try to link this object file into my executable, I get:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: error: ../fw_lib.a(fw_data.o): Conflicting CPU architectures 13/0
```

This seems to be because there is no ARM architecture data in the generated object. I've compared my generated fw_data.o to an object file generated by the compiler (main.o for example) using objdump and readelf. Object files that successfully link all seem to have the `.ARM.attributes` section which my generated object does not.

Just as a test, I manually dumped that section from main.o and added it to my objcopy command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --rename-section .data=.rodata,contents,alloc,load,readonly,data
    -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm prop_fw.bin fw_data.o
    --add-section .ARM.attributes=attributes_dump.bin
```

This successfully adds the section to the object, but the compiler does not seem to pick it up and it still fails to link. Comparing main.o and fw_data.o I see that the sections differ in their TYPE:

```
  main.o
  [31] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 001abc 000033 00      0   0  1
  fw_data.o
  [ 3] .ARM.attributes   PROGBITS        00000000 0078b9 000033 00      0   0  1
```

I have also tried dumping the .data section to a file and using ld to create fw_data.o as this question suggests: [What's the "correct" way to determine target and architecture for GNU binutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381254/whats-the-correct-way-to-determine-target-and-architecture-for-gnu-binutils/11742719)

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --dump-section .data=fw_data.bin -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm prop_fw.bin
arm-none-eabi-ld -r -b binary -A elf32-littlearm -o fw_data.o fw_data.bin
```

This leads to the same problem with the generated `fw_data.o` and it still fails to link.

How can I properly set the ARM_ATTRIBUTES section in an object file that I am generating with objcopy?

Comment: `This leads to the same problem with the generated fw_data and it still fails to link.` - that just _has to_ mean you are linking with conflicting cpu architectures. There is also missing argument `fw_data.bin` to ld, but I guess that's a typo. `ld` just compiles the binary data, it has to link properly.

Comment: @KamilCuk Dumping the object files with `readelf -A` yields the output `M4 Cortex ARM v7` for gcc compiled objects such as main.o. For fw_data.o, it prints nothing. You are correct, there is a conflicting cpu architecture between the binaries, `M4 Cortex ARM v7` and `ARM UNKNOWN`. That's the question: How do set the proper CPU attributes in the generated binary so that the architecture does not conflict?